# Querying multiple promises with a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, asynchronous, mapr

In node.js i have a `databaseMapper.js` file, that uses the Ojai node MapR api. to extract data. So far i have it working with single documents, but since this is an async api, i have a bit of issues with querying multiple documents.

This is what i have so far:

```js
function queryResultPromise(queryResult) {
//this should handle multiple promises
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        queryResult.on("data", resolve);
        // ...presumably something here to hook an error event and call `reject`...
    });
}



const getAllWithCondition = async (connectionString, tablename, condition) =>{
    const connection = await ConnectionManager.getConnection(connectionString);
    try {
        const newStore = await connection.getStore(tablename);
        const queryResult = await newStore.find(condition);
        return await queryResultPromise(queryResult);
    } finally {
        connection.close();
}
}
```

here it will only return the first because `queryResultPromise` will `resolve` on the first document.. however the callback with `"data"` may occur multiple times, before the queryResult will end like this `queryResult.on('end', () => connection.close())`

i tried using something like `Promise.all()` to resolve all of them, but I'm not sure how i include the `queryResult.on` callback into this logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
    const queryResultPromise = (queryResult) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let result = [];
            queryResult.on('data', (data) => {
                result.push(data)
            });
            queryResult.on('end', (data) => {
                resolve(result);
            });
            queryResult.on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            })
        });
    };
```